# IonImg shows as broken image when i load my page

Tags: javascript, image, ionic-framework, tsx, ionic-react

I'm using the Ionic version 5.4.16tag and i used the  to display an image in my web app, but the image shows as broken image in when i load the page, why is this happening and how do I fix it; Image is attached below:
this is the code i use to create the image:

```
<!-- language: tsx -->

    <IonRow className="ion-justify-content-center ion-text-center">
    <IonCol></IonCol>
    <IonCol size="3">
      <IonImg src="icon.png" />
      <div className="spinner">erie</div>
    </IonCol>
    <IonCol></IonCol>
    </IonRow>
```

[image]

Comment: the ion-image source needs to be updated, u need to put the relative path :)

Comment: that's the thing the image is in the same folder so i'm putting just the name, i also tried "./icon.png"

Comment: `ion-img` have some issues. Try using simple `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You must import the image before you use in IonImg component. For instance:

```js
import myImage from './icon.png'
```

...

```html
<IonImg src={myImage} />
```